# How to get the response headers from gapi.client endpoints

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I get the response headers from

`gapi.client.myEndpoint.myRpc().execute(function(response){console.log('Need the response headers')})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inspect response headers in this manner. Endpoints API system doesn't even supply a way for you to modify or set the headers. Header inspection/modification is something you should do in a normal handler.

At best, I can give this advice. If you use the function [`gapi.client.request()` method](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs?_ga=1.112772036.1307365166.1417540111#gapiclientrequest), you can hit the REST endpoints for your API, and this function returns a [`gapi.client.Request` object](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs?_ga=1.112772036.1307365166.1417540111#gapiclientRequest). Calling `.execute()` on this object will allow you to pass a callback function which will receive the response, including headers.